# Subsetting a data.frame based on a condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to subset a `data.frame` based on a condition in r. I have the following `data.frame` :

```
df

id     |    message      |     cluster
-------+-----------------+----------------
1      | Test A          | 1
2      | Test B          | 1
3      | Test C          | 3
4      | Test D          | 1
5      | Test E          | 2 
6      | Test F          | 2
7      | Test G          | 3
8      | Test H          | 3
9      | Test I          | 1 
10     | Test K          | 2
11     | Test L          | 4
12     | Test M          | 4
```

I want to construct a new `data.frame` with 4 (number of distinct cluster) rows. I choose the first `message` as representative of the cluster. So I want to get the following `data.frame` :

```
df2

id     |    message      |     cluster
-------+-----------------+----------------
1      | Test A          | 1
3      | Test C          | 3
5      | Test E          | 2 
11     | Test L          | 4
```

Comment: `df2 <- do.call(rbind, by(df, df$cluster, function(x) head(x, 1)))`

Comment: Please provide your example data in a reproducible format such as `dput`

Comment: or `df2 <- df[!duplicated(df$cluster), ]` will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the indices of the rows you want to collect:

```
indices <- !duplicated(df$cluster)
```

Use that to subset the dataframe:

```
df2 <- df[indices, ]
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative approach, the `dplyr` package is nice for these kinds of things.

```
text <- "id     |    message      |     cluster
1      | Test A          | 1
2      | Test B          | 1
3      | Test C          | 3
4      | Test D          | 1
5      | Test E          | 2
6      | Test F          | 2
7      | Test G          | 3
8      | Test H          | 3
9      | Test I          | 1
10     | Test K          | 2
11     | Test L          | 4
12     | Test M          | 4"

library(readr)
df <- read_delim(text, delim = "|", trim_ws=TRUE) 

library(dplyr)
df2 <-
    df %>% 
    group_by(cluster) %>%
    summarize(message=first(message))
```

And here's the result:

```
> df2
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  cluster message
    <int>   <chr>
1       1  Test A
2       2  Test E
3       3  Test C
4       4  Test L
```

(It might be useful to `arrange` the data so that "first" is predictable.)